# css - in print, big header not be repeated

Tags: html, css, printing

i want print a page, this page have a big header(in height).
but when i see `print preview`, only header show on the first page.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@page {
  margin: 0px;
  size: A4 landscape;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table style="width: 98%;margin: auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:300px; background-color:gray;border:1px solid">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="rows">
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>rows</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:300px; background-color:gray;border:1px solid"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6mvucked/

I've tested , and i am sure this problem is in header size because when resize header under 100px , that will work.

how i can increase header size ?

What is your solution?

Comment: You should probably use a print media query, and then learn print styles and print units ([one article](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/make-your-website-printable-css-3132929), [another](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/)). Specifically note [`page-break-*`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/). A table is one chunk, so I am not surprised that you have having problems.

Comment: i can't find anything. seems this is a actual problem.